# How can I reuse parts of the last command / history

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, command-history

I'm looking for a fast and efficient way to re-use the parameters of the last command in a new command. For example, in a Bash shell you can use the `$1` placeholder to reuse the 1st argument of the last command, `$!` to reuse the last argument, etc. In a Fish shell you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> keys to bring up the parameters of the complete history.

A regular use case is that I want to re-use parts of a file name I used in a previous command. If the file is still open, I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>%</kbd> in the command line, but if I switched files, I have to open the command history, look for the command and copy the file name.

Ideally, I'd like to have an autocomplete-like key binding in the command line that allows me to skip though parts of the history just like I would skip through file names when hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: At that point, I would probably `q:k` and start editing the previous command

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I just learned about `q:` and it's a bit of a game-changer.

Comment: `q:` and `h k j l` are hard to beat. Don't be afraid to `:q` to escape back to Normal Mode after `q:`. I feel that's what has people shying away from `q` commands in general (fear of quitting out of Vim entirely). @D.BenKnoble

Comment: `q:` has already been mentioned. Besides that, there is also `:<C-N>`, `:<C-P>`, and `:<C-F>`.

Answer (score 2):

> A regular use case is that I want to re-use parts of a file name I used in a previous command. If the file is still open, I could use `<Ctrl-R %>` in the command line, but if I switched files, I have to open the command history, look for the command and copy the file name.

`#` is the name of the "alternate file". It can be inserted with `<C-r>#` or used directly, just like `%`. See `:help cmdline-special`.

There is no universal "last command argument" or "last filename used". The last command can be retrieved with `:help histget()` but, even then, what you get is only a string because that's what is stored… so you will have to split, quote, etc… Nothing as easy as `$_` and friends but that sounds like an interesting week-end project.

Answer (score 0):

```
function! CompleteCommand(arg)
    call fzf#run({'source': GetCommands(),'sink': function('HandleCommand'),'options': '-m --query "'.a:arg.'"'} ) 
endfunction 

function! GetCommands()
    let lines=[]
    let nu=histnr("cmd")
    for i in range(1,nu)
        let lines+=[histget("cmd",i)]
    endfor
    return lines
endfunction

:cmap <expr> <c-a> &cedit.'^"xy$'."<esc><esc>:call CompleteCommand(@x)<CR>"
```

You start to type a command in the command line (`:`), and using FZF plugin, it allows you to fuzzy search commands that has part of it.

(That is done by pressing `<c-a>`)

requires

```
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
``
```